# Pick random elements from list and then remove them from original list

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import random

dominos_set = [[i, n] for i in range(0, 7) for n in range(0, 7) if i >= n]
stock = random.choices(dominos_set, k = 14)

for i in stock:
    for n in dominos_set:
        if n == i:
            dominos_set.remove(i)

print(dominos_set)
```

What I want to do:

1. I create 26 elements in **dominos_set**
2. I took 14 random elements from **dominos_set** (**stock**)
3. I want to remove 14 elements from **dominos_set** which I pointed in **stock**.

The problem is that every output of **dominos_set** is different every time in output: 18, 20, 14 and so on. I cant understand why is it happening? Can someone explain we what is not right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: You don't need that inner loop at all.  You KNOW that all of your choices are in the set.  Just do `for i in stock:` / `dominos_set(remove(i))`.  Or, even simpler, `dominos_set -= set(stock)`.  Sets support set subtraction.

Comment: The real answer to your question is that `random.choices` does not guarantee 14 DIFFERENT choices.  You're getting duplicates.  A better way to do what you're doing is to use `random.shuffle` and then pull the top 14 items.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, 
`for i in stock:
    dominos_set.remove(i)` this one doesnt work. You mean I should format dominos_set as set and stock also?

Comment: @Tim Roberts, thats clear now, thanx. How can I use random.shuffle for 14 elements?

Comment: You `random.shuffle` the entire list, then grab `dominos_set[:14]`, or use `.pop(0)` to pop 14 off the top.  And I'm sorry, when I read your code, I thought you were already using a set, not a list.  That's why my comments seemed like garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

dominos_set = [[i, n] for i in range(0, 7) for n in range(0, 7) if i >= n]
random.shuffle(dominos_set)
stock = dominos_set[:14]
players_set = [dominos_set.remove(n) for i in stock for n in dominos_set if i == n]
```

this will be the best solution. thanx @Tim Roberts

Comment: The `.remove()` method returns `None`, so currently you'll end up with a list of `None`'s for `players_set`.  If you just want to remove the `stock` list items from `dominos_set`, you can use list comprehension: `dominos_set = [elem for elem in dominos_set if elem not in stock]`.